# Pydev: How to import a gae project to eclipse Pydev gae project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pydev

Created a gae project with the googleappengine launch and have been building it with textmate.

Now, I'd like to import it to the Eclipse PyDev GAE project. Tried to import it, but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you haven't deleted .project and .pydevproject file, using `File - Import - General - Existing Projects into Workspace`

Comment: It doesn't work this way. I'm not able to click the finish button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try *not* using the eclipse import feature. Within Eclipse, create a new PyDev GAE project, and then you can copy in your existing files.

Comment: This works fine. You can drag your files to your new project folder. When you create a new PyDev Google App Engine Project project, I recommend not to use the "create src folder" option.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps: no matter if you (have / have not) committed your changes to SVN / GIT

```
- create a new PyDev GAE project
 - Name the project
 - Then on the same window under Project contents:- uncheck Use Default and select the directory where your Scripts / src files are located.
 - Set Google App Engine Configuration - Path to the Google App Engine folder that you downloaded.
 - Select all, for libraries.
 - Then select Empty project
 - Now your project is created
 - Hit finish !!! you are good to go.
```

Changes made on file in eclipse will reflect in your src files also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Eclipse's Import feature, go with General -> File system.